# Use arrow keys to move between Storyboard elements in Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, interface-builder

Is there a key combination that will allow you to use arrow keys to move between Storyboard objects, instead of moving the selected object?

Or a way to modify <kbd>Tab</kbd> key behavior to go 'top to bottom' instead of 'left to right'?

I can't find an answer despite a lot of searching.